# Queue of window.setTimeout(handler, delay)

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

If I keep adding javascript handler with a certain delay using

```
window.setTimeout
```

This will add all the timeout handler in a queue.
   When they start executing is there a guarantee that all the timeout handlers will get executed in the same order, as they were added. Assuming the delay is same for all the handlers.

```
window.setTimeout(handler1, 100);
window.setTimeout(handler2, 100);
window.setTimeout(handler3, 100);
window.setTimeout(handler4, 100);
```

In above example is the order of execution is guaranteed to be handler1 then handler2 then handler3 then handler4? or can they execute in any order?

I have tried with small examples and it seems that all handlers gets executed in proper order, but want to make sure if this is how all browsers will behave.

Comment: I don't have an authoritative source, but they should execute in order.  http://jsfiddle.net/Ebkuk/

Comment: Yes thats the concern, http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#timers says all timer handlers will go into a queue but can we assume queue order will be followed

Comment: I would rely on them executing in order (although they probably will), but what *exactly* are you trying to achieve? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @MattBurland: Do you mean "wouldn't rely"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Whoops, yes - that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The methods of the window object, including setTimeout, are covered by [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#timers). There is a section on how events are queued. It does not specify anything about the order in which items will be queued if they have the same timeout value. Therefore, I do not think you can rely on any particular behavior in this regard; browsers are free to implement them as they wish.